# Azure DevOps CD Pipeline with private Docker Hub

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to create a CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps for my Application. With the Build Pipeline section I have no problem. It's a react app which gets build and hosted (nginx) via a Docker Container. So building the Docker Container and pushing it to my private Docker Hub is no problem, that will work.But I actually can't figure out how to configure the release pipeline to deploy to a Azure WebApp for Containers with a private Docker Hub. Because there is no option for a service connection or Login Credentials to Configure. Would be nice if someone could help me and give a hint.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I actually can't figure out how to configure the release pipeline
> to deploy to a Azure WebApp for Containers with a private Docker Hub.
> Because there is no option for a service connection or Login
> Credentials to Configure. Would be nice if someone could help me and
> give a hint.

You don't need to provide `service connection or Login Credentials of private Docker Hub` within the `Azure Web App For containers` task or `Azure App Service Deploy` task.

Instead you should configure the credentials in `Azure Web Portal`. Go `Azure Web Portal`=>App Service=>Settings=>Container Settings you'll see:

[image]

You can enter your credentials there or you can configure the credentials when creating Azure App Service.

Since your `Azure App Service` can access your Private Docker Hub and deployment tasks in Azure Devops pipeline can access the `Azure App Service` with `Azure Subscription` input, the `Azure WebApp for Containers` task can automatically access the Private Docker Hub registry. (That's why you don't have/need an option to provide credentials of private docker hub!)

Comment: @Christoph Glad to know it helps :)